# Managing space in columns in QGIS legend

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

Is there a way to set up a legend so the group name spans multiple columns in QGIS print composer?
Trying to set up a legend where one of the items is split into columns, but the group spans the columns.  Using multiple legends, I was able to achieve something close to what I am looking for, but in the layer that is split into columns, there is a space that seems to be left over from the group name that I cannot get rid of to make the columns even.

I'm showing the frame on the second legend entry to show what's happening, in practice the frame is hidden so it appears to be one block.  The main legend  has a single column for the items that span the entire width.  The secondary one is split into columns, and just has one layer in it.  I want the name of the layer to span both columns, so need to include it in both legends, but hide the name in the secondary legend, but print composer leaves a space when I hide the layer name.  I'm suppressing the name of the layer by editing it within the legend entry.

[image: What I have]  [image: with frame]

What I'm looking for is to have the columns even like this (achieved by image editing):

[image: What I want]

Is there a different way to hide group or layer names so they don't create a space, or alternative way to split an individual layer into columns without splitting others?

Comment: On the second legend you can make the font size smaller, that will make the gap smaller (but still there). Or you can make two small legends, and manually remove half of the categories. In my experience the legend in QGIS often requires this sort of fiddling.